# How to block/disable internet for one user in Windows 7 while keeping internet access for other users?

Tags: windows, internet, blocking

The internet is distracting me from my writing. I'm about to cancel it, but my wife wouldn't be too happy with that. She uses it for research, and so on. I'd like to block my account from having access completely, while allowing her account to keep its access. I've Googled, but have come up short. Any help appreciated.

Comment: wired or wireless connection to the internet?

Answer (score 1):

Using group policy, you can disable the hardware required to connect (be it ethernet or wifi) for a user.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day, anything you do can be undone by yourself. I'd suggest using a wired connection for internet access, and handing the ethernet cable over to the wife when you need any serious work done.

Alternately you can set up a limited user account, and use parental controls to disable *all* internet related software (or anything that's not absolutely necessary)

And of course, let your wife handle access to the admin account if you end up using a software based solution, since you'll be tempted to change it back.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows 7, then there is a simple link.  Right click your network icon on the  bottom of your screen and open up the Network and Sharing Center.

Then click the "Connect or Disconnect" link.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems a little cludgy, but you could deny your user account access to Firefox.exe, IExplore.exe, etc. Right-click the exe file, go to the Security tab, and click Edit. Deny yourself read and execute permissions.